# Very slow insert in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I’m using Cassandra 1.2.1, and I am using COPY command to insert millions of rows. Each row is 100 bytes long. The issue is that the insertion happens rather slowly, at rate of 1500 rows per second. We have 3 node cluster with 50 GB disk space each, and 4 GB RAM each. Cassandra process is running with max heap size of 1 GB. We are storing commit logs and data files on the same disk. What could be the cause of this behaviour? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What client are you using?? What type of column u r inserting?? What is the replication factor?? @ What consistency level are u writing data ??

Comment: It turns out COPY command is not optimized for writes. I got the answer through cassandra dev support, m trying my luck now with pycassa.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently as of now, they are not planning to improve the speed of COPY.

See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-4588